# IIS 7 binding for SSL

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-7

I have a machine with multiple websites. The websites do not use the same domain name. As an example one website is test.test1.com another is test.test2.com. I also have a UC certificate that lists all of the domains but it doesn't use the wildcard * in any of the domains. When I try to create bindings for each I can't add the host header to the binding for https. If I use appcmd for the second domain I can no longer access the first domain.

How do I setup the bindings so I can access test.test1.com as the default for port 443 and test.test2.com only when that is the host header?

Thanks for the help!!
Gary

Comment: It's interesting that someone would vote to close this question without explaining why.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS 7 you can not have SSL bindings based on host headers. If you want multiple sites with https and don't have a wildcard certificate, you have to use multiple IP addresses, one for each SSL site. Just add IP addresses to the OS and set up DNS entries for them, then you bind the sites against those IP addresses, not their host names.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I added 198.168.10.1 to the network adapter, added to DNS, and created a https binding but I'm still receiving an IE cannot display the page error message